# Wordpress não encontra Host Mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, osx, host

Estou tentando rodar o WorPress localmente no MAC, isso para trabalhar o site e depois de pronto subir para o servidor.

O MySQL está instalado no MAC em /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/ é acessado via console e está em localhost:3306.

O Apache é 2.4.25 e o PHP 5.6.30, estou usando os que já vem instalado no MAC, esta totalmente funcional na pasta /Users/MeuUsuario/ApacheService/PastaWordpress onde o Wordpress é aberto para configurar BD.

Gosto desta configuração pois ela é limpa e já esta intrínseca na MAC.

O problema é que para usar o Wordpress não encontra o host do Mysql para configurar o DB criado. Já tentei todos os meus conhecimentos.

Comment: Você consegue acessar o mysql através de alguma ferramenta de administração ou console do SQL?

Comment: Já verificou se o mysql está rodando?

Comment: Sim, consigo acessar o Mysql e utilizar normalmente pelo console, também consigo acessar sem problemas através do Mysql Workbench que informa o host como 127.0.0.1  porta 3306.

Comment: O Wordpress esta funcionado corretamente com o php e apache. O problema é que o Wordpress não enxerga o host do mysql.

Comment: O que tem no `define( 'DB_HOST )'` do seu wp-config.php?

Comment: wp-config.php contem `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas instalei o phpMyAdmin que funcionou perfeitamente e está com os seguintes parâmetros:  Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
Tipo de servidor: MySQL
Versão do servidor: 5.7.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Versão do protocolo: 10
Utilizador: root@localhost
Conjunto de caracteres do servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)